# Error "The field 'xxx' must be an array but is of type Object in document" on embedded document in symfony2 mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I am making an application in Symfony2 with a mongodb database. I am a little bit new in Symfony and Mongodb.

I have an document Section which has a field restrictions with EmbedMany.

This is the code:

```
class Section
{
    ....
    
    /** @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Restriction") */
    private $restrictions = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->restrictions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    
    /**
     * Add restriction
     *
     * @param DelfosBundle\Document\Restriction $restriction
     */
    public function addRestriction(\DelfosBundle\Document\Restriction $restriction)
    {
        $this->restrictions[] = $restriction;
    }

    /**
     * Remove restriction
     *
     * @param DelfosBundle\Document\Restriction $restriction
     */
    public function removeRestriction(\DelfosBundle\Document\Restriction $restriction)
    {
        $this->restrictions->removeElement($restriction);
    }

    /**
     * Get restrictions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $restrictions
     */
    public function getRestrictions()
    {
        return $this->restrictions;
    }
}
```

When I receive a form I add a new Restriction object into the Section document and save the document:

```
$formAdd->handleRequest($request);
if ($formAdd->isValid()) {
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
    $restriction = $formAdd->getData();
    $section->addRestriction($restriction);
    $dm->persist($section);
    $dm->flush();
}
```

Then I receive the next error in the flush method:
localhost:27017: The field 'restrictions' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: "e5a0aaa531153335963de37ccaa5f471"}

But the document is correctly saved with the restriction in the database.

These are the versions I am using:

```
david@pfc:/var/www/html/delfos$ php bin/console --version
Symfony version 2.8.3 - app/dev/debug

david@pfc:/var/www/html/delfos$ composer show -i
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.7             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.6.0             Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                 v1.3.0             Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.6.1             Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.4             Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.2              Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.3.0              Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/inflector                   v1.1.0             Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.5              A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1             Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/mongodb                     1.2.1              Doctrine MongoDB Abstraction Layer
doctrine/mongodb-odm                 1.0.5              Doctrine MongoDB Object Document Mapper
doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle          3.0.2              Symfony2 Doctrine MongoDB Bundle
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.4             Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle         dev-master e770bfa Symfony FOSUserBundle
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler v2.1.2             Composer script handling your ignored parameter file
ircmaxell/password-compat            v1.0.4             A compatibility library for the proposed simplified password hashing algorithm: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash
jdorn/sql-formatter                  v1.2.17            a PHP SQL highlighting library
kriswallsmith/assetic                v1.3.2             Asset Management for PHP
monolog/monolog                      1.17.2             Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
paragonie/random_compat              v1.2.0             PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
psr/log                              1.0.0              Common interface for logging libraries
sensio/distribution-bundle           v5.0.4             Base bundle for Symfony Distributions
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v3.0.13            This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sensio/generator-bundle              v3.0.6             This bundle generates code for you
sensiolabs/security-checker          v3.0.2             A security checker for your composer.lock
swiftmailer/swiftmailer              v5.4.1             Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/assetic-bundle               v2.7.1             Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
symfony/monolog-bundle               v2.8.2             Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge               v2.8.3             Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu                v1.1.0             Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu            v1.1.0             Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related data and classes
symfony/polyfill-mbstring            v1.1.0             Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php54               v1.1.0             Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.4+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php55               v1.1.0             Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.5+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php56               v1.1.0             Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php70               v1.1.0             Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util                v1.1.0             Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/security-acl                 v2.8.0             Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access Control List)
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v2.3.11            Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                      v2.8.3             The Symfony PHP framework
symfony/var-dumper                   v3.0.3             Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables
twig/twig                            v1.24.0            Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but : Try to remove the default value by : 'private $restrictions = array();'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem.

The embeded document definition has to bee @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument, and I was using @MongoDB\Document.

So in my case the Restriction class which is embeded inside the Section class must be defined like this:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Restriction
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    ....
}
```